# vb2008 insert and update record using one button

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to make a glossary. I have a form with a listbox, 2 textboxes, and a save button.

The listbox is now populated with words from the database, and when a word is selected, its definition will display in textbox2.

The user can add a record by filling the textbox1 with a new word and textbox2 with its definition,and clicking the save button. If the new word already existed it will not allow to save a new record, also if there's a null value between the 2 textboxes. If it doesn't exist it will be inserted on the table and the new word will be added to the listbox.

The user can also update the record by selecting first a word on the list then edit the word and/or definition and clicking the save button.

I already got the updating part to work but I have problem in inserting a new record. I can't do it properly. The glossary table has only 2 fields: word, definition. Here's my code:

```
Dim myCmd As New MySqlCommand
Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader
Dim myAdptr As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim myDataTable As New DataTable
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Call Connect()
    With Me
        If Blank() = False Then
            If Duplicate() = False Then
                STRSQL = "insert into glossary values (@word, @def)"
                myCmd.Connection = myConn
                myCmd.CommandText = STRSQL
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("word", txtNew.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("def", txtdefine.Text)
                myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                myCmd.Dispose()
                MsgBox("Record Added")
                Dim word As String
                word = txtNew.Text
                lstword.Items.Add(word)
                'myConn.Close()
                'Me.FillListbox()
            Else
                myConn.Open()
                STRSQL = "Update glossary set word = @term, definition = @mean where word = @term"
                myCmd.Connection = myConn
                myCmd.CommandText = STRSQL
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("term", txtNew.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("mean", txtdefine.Text)
                myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                myCmd.Dispose()
                MsgBox("Record Updated", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "New word added")
            End If
        End If
    End With


End Sub

Public Function Blank() As Boolean
    Call Connect()
    With Me
        If .txtNew.Text = "" Or .txtdefine.Text = "" Then
            Blank = True
            MsgBox("Cannot save! Term and definition should not contain null value", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Unable to save")
        Else
            Blank = False
        End If
    End With
End Function

Public Function Duplicate() As Boolean
    Call Connect()
    With Me
        STRSQL = "Select * from glossary where word = '" & txtNew.Text & "'"
        myCmd.Connection = myConn
        myCmd.CommandText = STRSQL
        If myDataTable.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            Duplicate = True
            'MsgBox("Word already exist. Please check the word.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Duplicate.")

        Else
            Duplicate = False
        End If
        myConn.Close()
    End With
End Function
```

this is my connection module:

```
Public myConnectionString As String
Public STRSQL As String
Public myConn As New MySqlConnection
Public Sub Connect()
    With myConn
        Try
            If .State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                .Close()
            End If
            myConnectionString = "Database=firstaidcqs;Server=localhost;Uid=root;Password="
            .ConnectionString = myConnectionString
            .Open()
            'MsgBox("Successful Connection")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Connection Error")
            .Close()
        End Try
    End With
End Sub
Public Sub Disconnect()
    With myConn
        .Close()
        .Dispose()
    End With
End Sub
```

How can I make this work properly?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Also, ever heard of SQL injection?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: what happened is that when a word is selected from the list, the word and definition displays and can be updated. There's no problem with this anymore. The problem is that when I try to insert a new record, it says 'Parameter 'term' has already been defined.' on the `myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("term", txtNew.Text)` part. It seems that when I tried to add another record, the last word selected is still open that's why this is happening..but its just a guess. What should I do so that I can insert a new record even if a word is already selected?..by the way, I used the mysql-5.5.27.

Comment: also if I insert a new record first before selecting any from the list, it says "Record Updated" instead of "Record added". Then when I checked the list and the table, nothing really happened :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using global variables in all the code above.

```
myConn and myCmd
```

in particular, you call Dispose on myCmd but I can't see anywhere the reinitialization of the object with New. Also, forgetting for a moment the myCmd.Dispose problem, you don't reset the myCmd parameters collection. In this way you end up with a wrong Parameter collection for the command executed, Also don't forget to open the connection for the insert part. (and close it for both parts)

You could easily avoid the use of unnecessary global variables

```
....
If Duplicate() = False Then
    STRSQL = "insert into glossary values (@word, @def)"
    Using myCmd = new MySqlCommand(STRSQL, myConn)
        myConn.Open()
        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("word", txtNew.Text)
        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("def", txtdefine.Text)
        myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    myConn.Close()
.....
Else
    STRSQL = "Update glossary set word = @term, definition = @mean where word = @term"
    Using myCmd = new MySqlCommand(STRSQL, myConn)
        myConn.Open()
        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("term", txtNew.Text)
        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("mean", txtdefine.Text)
        myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    myConn.Close()
.....
```

A better solution will be changing the Connect() method to return the initialized connection instead of using a global variable. In that way you could enclose also the creation and destruction of the connection in a Using statement

```
 Using myConn as MySqlConnection = Connect()
 .......
 End Using
```

For this to work you need to change the code of Connect in this way

```
Public Function Connect() as MySqlConnection
    Dim myConn As MySqlConnection
    myConnectionString = "Database=firstaidcqs;Server=localhost;Uid=root;Password="
    myConn = New MySqlConnection(myConnectionString)
    myConn.Open()
    return myConn
End Sub
```

No need of a `Disconnect` function because you will always use the [Using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) that will close the connection for you, no need to have a global variable to keep the connection because you will reopen the connection every time you need it and close afterward. Don't think that this is not performant because ADO.NET implements [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  (It is an MSDN article for SqlServer, but the concept applies also to MySql)

Comment: `Using myConn As MySqlConnection = Connect()`- I got an error saying 'Expression does not produce a value'

Comment: I can't see the code for Connect. Please add to your question above. In that method you should return an object of type MySqlConnection without using a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

yay!! I got it working now :D (my apology, it took me a long time to finish this..i'm still learning). Here's my final code:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Call Connect()
    If Blank() = False Then
        If Duplicate() = False Then
            STRSQL = "insert into glossary values (@word, @def)"
            Using myCmd = New MySqlCommand(STRSQL, myConn)
                myConn.Open()
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("word", txtNew.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("def", txtdefine.Text)
                myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
            myConn.Close()
            MsgBox("Record Added")
            Dim word As String
            word = txtNew.Text
            lstword.Items.Add(word)
            myConn.Close()
        Else
            STRSQL = "Update glossary set word = @term, definition = @mean where word = @term"
            Using myCmd = New MySqlCommand(STRSQL, myConn)
                myConn.Open()
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("term", txtNew.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("mean", txtdefine.Text)
                myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
            myConn.Close()
            MsgBox("Record Updated", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "New word added")
            Dim str As String
            str = txtNew.Text
            myConn.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Function Blank() As Boolean
    Call Connect()
    With Me
        If .txtNew.Text = "" Or .txtdefine.Text = "" Then
            Blank = True
            MsgBox("Cannot save! Term and definition should not contain null value", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Unable to save")
        Else
            Blank = False
        End If
    End With
End Function

Public Function Duplicate() As Boolean
    Dim dset As New DataSet
    Call Connect()
    With Me
        STRSQL = "Select * from glossary where word = '" & txtNew.Text & "'"
        myCmd.Connection = myConn
        myCmd.CommandText = STRSQL
        myAdptr.SelectCommand = myCmd
        myAdptr.Fill(dset, "glossary")
        myDataTable = dset.Tables("glossary")
        If myDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Duplicate = True
            'MsgBox("Word already exist. Please check the word.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Duplicate.")

        Else
            Duplicate = False
        End If
        myConn.Close()
    End With
End Function
```

I still used the my first module but I already removed the Disconnect() function. @Steve - thank you very much for the help sir, I'll try using what you suggested to me some time..maybe on my next program. God speed!! :)

Comment: If @Steve's answer was helpful, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. By doing so, you reward other members for helping you. In the long run, it makes your questions more likely to get an answer.